# Filla Datatable with a stored procedure result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to fill a DataTable with the results from the following stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    -- Simply example
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.canela', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE dbo.canela;    

    CREATE TABLE canela
    (
        [ColA] VARCHAR(200),
        [ColB] VARCHAR(100),
        [ColC] VARCHAR(100)
    );

    INSERT INTO canela([ColA], [ColB], [ColC]) 
    VALUES (@i + 12, 'Io', 'tu')

    SELECT * 
    FROM canela 
END
```

Here's my code:

```
public DataTable GetTableSqlFromSp(string sql)
{
    ErrorListMessages.ClearErrors();

    DataTable dt = null;

    if (ConnectionOpen())
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, Cnn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt = new DataTable());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorListMessages.SetInternalError(ex, string.Format("GetTableSql({0})", sql));
            return null;
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

And the SQL:

```
EXEC Antani @i = '8';
```

I got an error

> Syntax error or access violation

but I don't know why. If I fire my stored procedure directly in SQL Server, all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use System.Data.SqlClient.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC Antani @i = '8'", Cnn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  dt.Load(rdr);
}
```